# before_destroy callback does not register in production mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, callback

I used to be able to register a before_destroy callback for every ActiveRecord instance in my app via the following code in ./config/initializers/active_record_base.rb ...

```
class ActiveRecord::Base
    before_destroy :enumerate_descendants

    def enumerate_descendants(args={})
        # code...
    end
end
```

But now, in a Rails 3.2.9 and ruby 1.9.3p327 app, this only works in development mode and not production.  (From my controller I am calling destroy and not delete, btw.)  Some proof:

```
localhost:my_app me$ RAILS_ENV=development rails console
Loading development environment (Rails 3.2.9)
1.9.3-p327 :001 > Person._destroy_callbacks
 => [<ActiveSupport::Callbacks::Callback:0x007fbdde8f2890 @klass=ActiveRecord::Base, @kind=:before, 
@chain=[...], @per_key={:if=>[], :unless=>[]}, @options={:if=>[], :unless=>[]},
@raw_filter=:enumerate_descendants, @filter=:enumerate_descendants, @compiled_options="true", @callback_id=12>] 

localhost:my_app me$ RAILS_ENV=production rails console
Loading production environment (Rails 3.2.9)
1.9.3-p327 :001 > Person._destroy_callbacks
 => []
```

If I use config.cache_classes = false in ./environments/production.rb, the callback is registered in production mode, but that's obviously a problem for a production app...

So, any ideas -- other than a base class for all my models -- how I can get a before_destroy callback registered for all instances of ActiveRecord in production mode?

Thanks!

Comment: Can it be that your models are loaded before you open ActiveRecord::Base and define the callback? When `config.cache_classes` is false your "extension" of ActiveRecord::Base is not done again, and because of that it's there when the models are reloaded.

Answer (score 1):

As I wrote in my comment, this is probably because your models are loaded *before* you add the "before_destroy" in ActiveRecord::Base. In development environment (when `config.cache_classes = false`) the models are reloaded (for every request?), and then the "before_destroy" is already registered on ActiveRecord::Base.

**I have tested this in an old Rails, but I got the same behaviour**

You must find out where to use the code for register the "before_destroy" on ActiveRecord::Base so it's done *before* any model are loaded.

If you test this yourself with e.g. doing `require 'one_of_your_models'` in console to see if it works with reload, that is not enough, you must do `Object.send(:remove_const, :OneOfYourModels)` before the reload (Rails are doing that before the reload of the models).